# Stop time auto updating with amendment

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently using this following Macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim x As Long
x = Target.Row
If Target.Column = 2 Or Cells(x, 15) <> "" Or Target.Column = 3 Or Cells(x, 15) <> "" Then
Cells(x, 1) = time
Cells(x, 1).NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
End If
End Sub
```

This is great for what I wanted the spreadsheet to do in the first instance but now I need a little more amendment. 
I would like:

To remove the Macro from cells A1 and A2.

(probably the difficult part) Once an entry is made into column B, if an amendment needs to be made (I.E a spelling mistake is found) the time stamp will update to reflect the last change. Can the Macro be changed so the Time stamp entered in column A does not change from the first entry in column B.

Currently, the macro populates the time if anything is entered into column B. I cannot work out a way for it not to 'overwrite' the time with each amendment.

Hope you guys can help.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim x As Long
x = Target.Row
If Target.Column = 2 Or Cells(x, 15) <> "" Or Target.Column = 3 Or Cells(x, 15) <> ""   Then
    if Cells(x, 1) = "" then
        Cells(x, 1) = time
        Cells(x, 1).NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
    End If
End if
End Sub
```

You could try something like this.

Comment: Thanks for that but I cannot seem to get this working.
When I save the Macro and try and enter data, I get an error
"Block If without End If"

Comment: My bad, I worked it out :)
Just needed to add an extra End If before the End Sub.

Comment: I really appreciate your help on this. It seems so simple now I see the code. Thank you again